# pfctl - Allow ssh connection from specific IP, and block everyone else

Tags: unix, bsd, firewall-access

I'm working with pfctl on Mac OS X and I'm trying to make a policy/anchor what blocks SSH for ALL ips, but not for a specific ip. I try that:

```
pass in on en1 proto tcp from any to any port < 22 flags S/SA
pass out on en1 proto tcp from any to any port < 22 flags S/SA
pass in on en1 proto tcp from any to any port > 22  flags S/SA
pass out on en1 proto tcp from any to any port > 22 flags S/SA

block in on en1 proto tcp from any to any port 22 
block out on en1 proto tcp from any to any port 22
```

But the result is blocking all conections on port 22. Exist the possibility to allow SSH connection from specific ip? Or a table what a send a list of IPs what will connect on my system by SSH.

Best regards!